# SQL - Create an array based on the values of two other columns

Tags: sql, arrays, clickhouse

I have the following data:

```
-----------------------------------------
| client_id | link_hash_a | link_hash_b |
-----------------------------------------
|     1     |     abc     |     xyz     |
|     2     |     def     |     xyz     |
|     3     |     def     |     uvw     |
-----------------------------------------
```

I would like to create an array of client_id that are linked with the two hash values from the columns `link_hash_a` and `link_hash_b` using SQL.

In the current situation, the result would be a unique array with the value `{1,2,3}` because the clients 1 and 2 are linked with the value `xyz` of the `link_hash_b` column and the client 2 and 3 are linked with the value `def` of the `link_hash_a` column.

Is there a way to do that with an SQL query? Thank you really much for your input.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and only very few products truly support arrays). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I am using ClickHouse DBMS. It has a standard SQL language and works with arrays as well. The question is more about the way/strategy to play with the data to answer this need. As PostgreSQL works also with arrays, if you have the answer using PGSQL I will take it with pleasure ;)

Comment: Not clear whether is important the client 2 is connected to both clients 1 and 3 (to client 1 through hash a and to client 3 through hash b). If yes, it seems like some traversal problem (you will need recursive query, it is solvable with PG, can't tell about Clickhouse). If not, simple SQL based on two `group by`s (by either hash columns) should be sufficient.

Comment: I tried to use two `group by` queries on the first place and `join` them in a query to have their result in a single array, but I couldn't have the perfect array of `{1,2,3}`. I think I am close, but that's not it yet.

Comment: To answer your question @TomášZáluský, the client 2 is really important because as the fact he is sharing the same hash with client 3 with hash a and the same hash with client 1 with hash b, he permits to create the link between the client 1 and the client 3.

Comment: Please, (1) show, what you have achieved, (2) compose more complex example (with more links, isolated clients etc.), (3) present you input as Common Table Expression to make work more convenient for those who want to help.

Comment: @Ludo . . . To solve this with a single `SELECT` requires recursive CTEs (or a similar method to support hierarchical queries).  I don't think Clickhouse supports recursive CTEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative can be used this way:

```sql
SELECT groupUniqArrayArray(client_ids) client_ids
FROM (
  SELECT link_hash, groupArray(client_id) client_ids
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT client_id, arrayJoin([link_hash_a, link_hash_b]) as link_hash
    FROM (
      /* test data */
      SELECT data.1 client_id, data.2 link_hash_a, data.3 link_hash_b
      FROM (
        SELECT arrayJoin([
          (1, 'abc', 'xyz'),
          (2, 'def', 'xyz'),
          (3, 'def', 'uvw')]) data)))
  GROUP BY link_hash
  HAVING count() = 2)
/* result
┌─client_ids─┐
│ [2,1,3]    │
└────────────┘
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way through. I used another column which is the `club_id` of which the clients are part of. In this case, the clients 1, 2 and 3 are all part of the `club_id` 1 for example.

Here is my code using ClickHouse SQL and taken into account that `input_table` is the table of data as shown in the question:

```sql
SELECT club_id, arrayConcat( clt_a, clt_b ) as tot_clt_arr, arrayUniq( arrayConcat( clt_a, clt_b ) ) as tot_clt
FROM
(
    SELECT club_id, clt_a
    FROM
        (
        SELECT club_id, link_hash_a, groupUniqArray(client_id) as clt_a
        FROM input_table
        GROUP BY club_id, link_hash_a
        )
    WHERE length(clt_a) >= 2
) JOIN
(
    SELECT club_id, clt_b
    FROM
        (
        SELECT club_id, link_hash_b, groupUniqArray(client_id) as clt_b
        FROM input_table
        GROUP BY club_id, link_hash_b
        )
    WHERE length(clt_b) >= 2
)
USING club_id
GROUP BY club_id, tot_clt_arr;
```

It returns the array of `client_id` as well as the number of unique `client_id` in the `tot_clt` column.

Thank you @TomášZáluský for your help.